# Opening Multiple`.xls` files from a folder in a different directory and creating one dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operating-system

I am trying to open multiple `xls` files in a folder from a particular directory. I wish to read into these files and open all of them in one data frame. So far I am able to access the directory and put all the `xls` files into a list like this

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = ('D:\Anaconda Hub\ARK analysis\data\year2021\\february') 
files = os.listdir(path)

files
# outputting the variable files which appears to be a list. 
Output:
['ARK_Trade_02012021_0619PM_EST_601875e069e08.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02022021_0645PM_EST_6019df308ae5e.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02032021_0829PM_EST_601b2da2185c6.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02042021_0637PM_EST_601c72b88257f.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02052021_0646PM_EST_601dd4dc308c5.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02082021_0629PM_EST_6021c739595b0.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02092021_0642PM_EST_602304eebdd43.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02102021_0809PM_EST_6024834cc5c8d.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02112021_0639PM_EST_6025bf548f5e7.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02122021_0705PM_EST_60270e4792d9e.xls',
 'ARK_Trade_02162021_0748PM_EST_602c58957b6a8.xls']
```

I am now trying to get it into one dataframe like this:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    frame.append(data)
    
df = pd.concat(frame, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

However, when doing this I sometimes obtain a blank data frame or it throws an error like this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ARK_Trade_02012021_0619PM_EST_601875e069e08.xls'
```

Help would truly be appreciated with this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens because if you simply put the file name the interpreter assumes that it is in the current working directory, therefore you need to use `os` module to get proper location:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = ('D:\Anaconda Hub\ARK analysis\data\year2021\\february') 
files = os.listdir(path)

#frame = pd.DataFrame()   ...This will not work!
frame = []  # Do this instead 

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, f), 'Sheet1')  # Here join filename with folder location
    frame.append(data)
    
df = pd.concat(frame, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

The other issue is that `frame` should be a list or some other iterable. Pandas has `append` method for dataframes but if you want to use `concat` then it will need to be a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a middle step to check if the path exists or not, I suspect this is an isolated issue with your server, from memory when working on older windows servers (namely 2012), I would sometimes have issues where the Path couldn't be found even though it 100% existed.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path 

# assuming you want xls and xlsx. 
files = Path('folder_location').glob('*.xls*') 

dfs = []

for file in files:
    if file.is_file():
        df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='sheet')
        dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: both solutions above output this error :` CompDocError: Workbook corruption: seen[2] == 4`

Comment: @DeepakM error is clear, means your excel file is corrupt.